# Enabling basic authentication in webview without custom WebViewClient in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using a webview in my Xamarin Forms project with `Hybrid Renderer` and `webview`, because I have to inject javascript code inside the page.

In my main project I have a `CustomWebview.cs`:

```
namespace ClotureSiadForms.Renderer
{
    public class CustomWebView : WebView
    {
        public string js = "";

        public CustomWebView()
        {
            Navigating+= WebViewNavigating;
            Navigated+=WebViewNavigated;
        }

        private void WebViewNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs args)
        {
            EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(js);
        }

        public void WebViewNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Url.StartsWith("tel:"))
            {
                var tel = args.Url.Split(':')[1];
                args.Cancel = true;

                Xamarin.Essentials.PhoneDialer.Open(tel);
            }
            else if (!args.Url.StartsWith("http") || args.Url.EndsWith(".apk") || args.Url.EndsWith(".pdf") || args.Url.EndsWith(".zip"))
            {
                args.Cancel = true;
                Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync(args.Url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my Android project I have a `HybridWebViewRenderer.cs`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace ClotureSiadForms.Droid.Renderer
{
    internal class HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                CustomWebView webview = e.NewElement as CustomWebView;

                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
                Control.Settings.SavePassword = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As is, it worked and was able to download files
But as I needed basic authentication, I added a custom webviewclient inside `HybridWebViewRenderer.cs`:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            CustomWebView webview = e.NewElement as CustomWebView;

            Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.SavePassword = true;

            var login = Preferences.Get("login", "");
            var password = Preferences.Get("password", "");
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new AuthWebViewClient(login, password));
        }
    }
    public class AuthWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        private string Username;
        private string Password;
        public AuthWebViewClient(string username, string password)
        {
            Username = username;
            Password = password;
        }
        public override void OnReceivedHttpAuthRequest(Android.Webkit.WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, string host, string realm)
        {
            handler.Proceed( Username,Password);
        }
    }
```

And authentication works, but `WebViewNavigating` is now called once, then the custom client is set and then `WebViewNavigating` is never more called.

Then my question is, can't I use basic auth without a custom client or is there a way to keep using my `customwebview` with the client ?

Answer (score 0):

> And authentication works, but `WebViewNavigating` is now called once, then the custom client is set and then `WebViewNavigating` is never more called.

I tested the code you provided and added Breakpoint to `WebViewNavigating` method. Even if you do not add `webviewclient`, it will only call `WebViewNavigating` once.

You can put the code in `WebViewNavigating` to `ShouldInterceptRequest`:

```
 public class AuthWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        ...
        public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            var url = request.Url;
            ...
        }
    }
```

Whenever the WebView begins loading a new page, it will call `ShouldInterceptRequest`.